# Find the Particular Solution of the following system using the Laplace Transform method:

Tags: laplace-transform

$x' = x - 2y$

$y' = 3x - 4y$

$x(0) = 1$

$y(0) = 1$

How would the Laplace Transform method differ from the usual methods? My first thought is that I should equate the two equations using $x$ or $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Laplace transforming we have

$$
sX = X-2Y+x_0\\
sY = 3X-4Y + y_0
$$

Now solving for $X,Y$

$$
X = \frac{(s+4) x_0-2 y_0}{s^2+3 s+2},Y = \frac{(s-1) y_0+3 x_0}{s^2+3 s+2}
$$

so

$$
x = e^{-2 t} \left(e^t (3 x_0-2 y_0)-2 x_0+2 y_0\right)u(t)\\
y = e^{-2 t} \left(3 \left(e^t-1\right) x_0+\left(3-2 e^t\right) y_0\right)u(t)
$$

with $u(t)$ the unit step function

etc.